# Devise after_sign_up_path_for not being called

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am using Devise with multiple models for authentication, Admin and User. On a User signup I want to redirect to a profile page. (Admins are created using a rake task, or through the admin Admin pages, not by going through a registration process.)

I am using Ruby 2.0.0, Rails 4, and Devise 3.1.0.

This is the code I am using to do the redirect, as per help here on StackOverflow and on the Devise GitHub page.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
    protect_from_forgery
    before_filter :authenticate_user!

    def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
        Rails.logger.info('ApplicationController: after_sign_up_path_for called')
        '/profile'
    end

    def after_inactive_sign_up_path_for(resource)
        Rails.logger.info('ApplicationController: after_inactive_sign_up_path_for called')
        '/profile'
    end
end
```

However, when I run the through the signup, it appears that neither the after_sign_up or the after_inactive_sign_up methods are called, as no logging appears.

Now I've done some hunting around and I can't seem to find anything wrong with my code. I am wondering if it is due to the multiple model model I am using.

Can anyone shed some light on this?

If you need to see more code or other info, please ask.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Read the devise wiki on github.

Here is the related link

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Redirect-to-a-specific-page-on-successful-sign-in,-sign-up,-or-sign-out

Comment: Thank you. That helped. After all it turned out I was missing  :controllers => { :registrations => "registrations" } on the route (after using Sunils advice above.) Cheers.

Comment: As of Oct 2018, that Devise wiki page is blank.  ??

Comment: I believe this is the updated page: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Redirect-to-a-specific-page-on-successful-sign-in,-sign-up,-or-sign-out

Comment: Thanks @user2490003 Updated now.

Answer (score 4):

You cant override this method in application controller.
You have to override registrations_controller of devise like this:

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

  protected

  def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
    # your path
  end
end
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: Thanks Sunil, however I tried changing to RegistrationsController and no luck. Also, the devise wiki indicates that this should be done in the ApplicationController. Still not sure why this doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [this](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Change-the-redirect-path-after-destroying-a-session-i.e.-signing-out). You need to do a few more changes before it start working.

You should also override method `Devise::Controllers::Helpers#stored_location_for` in your application controller, to return `nil`. This applies to `after_sign_in_path_for` also.

Secondly, the methods `after_sign_up_path_for` and `after_inactive_sign_up_path_for` should be privale.

Comment: Thanks for the help. A couple of things though. I'm not sure how to actually set this item to nil? (as #stored_location... resolves to a comment.) And from the link, this seems to be the process for when you sign out, not sign up.

Comment: I also added both private and protected. No joy.

Answer (score 1):

I was running into a similar problem as John Judd. Reading through the documentation that Rahul Singh was kind enough to point to, I realized that I needed to update my `routes.rb` file because devise was unaware of the overriden`Devise::RegistrationsController`.

Here is what my `routes.rb` file had:

```
devise_for :users
```

I replaced it with this:

```
devise_for :users, controllers: { registrations: "registrations" }
```

That solved my problem.